# filtering rows of text file based on the columns in python or R

Tags: python, r, file, row

I have a big text file with 32000 rows and 51 columns.

Rows are genes and columns are samples. Each cell contains the values of each gene in each sample.

I want to remove those genes (rows) which have more than 10 values less or equal to 2. As an example, `0 1 2 3 4 5` has only three values less than or equal to 2, so should be kept.

I used the following piece of code to do that, but after running it I still I have many rows with more than 10 values less than or equal to 2:

```
output_file = open("results.txt", 'w')
for line in open(input_filepath, 'r'):
  values = line.split(' ')
  if len([value for value in values[1:] if float(value) <= 2]) <= 10:
      output_file.write(line)
```

This is the first line and the other ones are like it:

```
ENSG00000000003.10  17.83196398 69.91920499 279.89049   95.61821179 74.80702449 122.5556208 144.8049767 68.68034587 73.67798573 89.95469195 81.85856972 126.9733354 64.93879738 29.4107548  73.03579221 116.0315804 67.90288741 27.57208264 62.52823427 99.03510023 9.39397698  61.45042154 117.1267932 63.15944291 319.4942754 142.3189945 59.98822761 173.5042114 67.29941051 97.12375332 37.94666697 137.0865621 91.06779336 71.44276982 79.58113909 221.2371603 38.62588269 122.5556208 111.12162   260.6636398 184.7700916 100.6786557 97.59881552 264.2982916 161.1062423 92.55084782 64.8034559  117.3666154 89.70704223 51.63439938
```

Comment: exactly. for example in the particular row there are at least 10 columns with the value between 0 and 2

Comment: so I wanna remove those rows

Comment: The code you shows looks correct, so it's hard to debug from here. To help you debug I recommend sticking that `len` expression into a variable and temporarily emitting it to the output file together with the `line` so you can see what the code **thought** the `len` expression was -- then you can dig down into **why** it thought that, which at this point is unclear.

Comment: @ali, note that the "first line" shown in your Q only has less than 20 columns, not 60, so it's impossible to see a problem -- you may want to edit your Q to fix that (may have been broken during the many edits needed to fix your code's formatting, which was unreadable).

Comment: somebody just edited the code. I think he deleted the other columns

Comment: This is completely tangential to the question, but please use `with` for files.

Comment: @ali, there were 4 edits (needed to make your post more readable, and particularly to fix your code's format) but I just checked the original (in the revisions history) and you posted a "first line" with just 17 fields from the very start -- nobody else removed anything from that line.

Comment: Alex it is done in the Q. it has 51 columns

Comment: There are **no** values <= 2 in the `first line` now fully present in the Q, so how are we supposed to reproduce your problem?!  One clear bug in your code is that you use `.split(' ')` rather than `.split()`, since the line you show clearly has **multiple** spaces as separators; but if your code was indeed as you show it, this would cause a `ValueError` (on calling `float` on an empty string).  IOW, it's impossible that the Python code you show would run w/o exceptions on the `line` you also show.  You're **not** making it easy to help you, you know!-)

Comment: this is the first line just to show you the data structure

Answer (score 2):

Using R this is simple:

```
#some example data
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), ncol=3))
DF <- cbind(id=letters[1:10], DF)

#    id          X1         X2         X3
# 1   a  1.37095845  1.3048697 -0.3066386
# 2   b -0.56469817  2.2866454 -1.7813084
# 3   c  0.36312841 -1.3888607 -0.1719174
# 4   d  0.63286260 -0.2787888  1.2146747
# 5   e  0.40426832 -0.1333213  1.8951935
# 6   f -0.10612452  0.6359504 -0.4304691
# 7   g  1.51152200 -0.2842529 -0.2572694
# 8   h -0.09465904 -2.6564554 -1.7631631
# 9   i  2.01842371 -2.4404669  0.4600974
# 10  j -0.06271410  1.3201133 -0.6399949

#remove rows if more than 2 values <= 0
DF[rowSums(DF[, -1] <= 0) <= 2,]
#    id         X1         X2         X3
# 1   a  1.3709584  1.3048697 -0.3066386
# 2   b -0.5646982  2.2866454 -1.7813084
# 3   c  0.3631284 -1.3888607 -0.1719174
# 4   d  0.6328626 -0.2787888  1.2146747
# 5   e  0.4042683 -0.1333213  1.8951935
# 6   f -0.1061245  0.6359504 -0.4304691
# 7   g  1.5115220 -0.2842529 -0.2572694
# 9   i  2.0184237 -2.4404669  0.4600974
# 10  j -0.0627141  1.3201133 -0.6399949
```

This uses conversion of logical values to 0/1 when they are passed to `rowSums`.

Comment: Are you serious? Read a tutorial.